# Raspberry Pi Model A+: I2S ADC and DAC connection

Tags: audio, analog-to-digital

I want to connect raspberry pi A+ to external DAC/ADC(audio codec) via I2S interface. Is it possible? If not, what model can I use to perform audio recording/streaming?

Comment: Yes it's possible. I have done this with the [max98357 class D mono amplifier](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-max98357-i2s-class-d-mono-amp) from adafruit. The link contains a tutorial, which guides you step by step. Good luck

Comment: Recording and playback seems to be possible too but a bit tricky as you can see here https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/90647/i2s-recording-combined-with-i2s-playback