# I2S Recording combined with I2S Playback

Tags: gpio, pi-zero-w, output, i2s, adafruit

I have a Raspberry Pi Zero and I am using the [Adafruit I2S MEMS Microphone](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3421) together with the [ADAFRUIT I2S 3W CLASS D AMPLIFIER BREAKOUT - MAX98357A](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3006).

I did follow the two respective tutorials and I got both the mic and the speaker working. However, I do need to disable the microphone or the amp + speaker won't work.

There seems to be a conflict regarding the I<sup>2</sup>S bus.

According to [this forum post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=183617#p1385657) it can be done.

[image: pi zero]

**Update**:

I have the following `/etc/modules`:

```
i2c-dev
snd-bcm2835
my_loader
```

The `/boot/config.txt` looks like so:

```
# ... 
dtparam=i2s=on
# ... 
dtparam=audio=on 
dtoverlay=hifiberry-dac 
dtoverlay=i2s-mmap
```

This is what I see in `dmesg` when I have both the mic and the amplifier enabled:

> [   13.039895] asoc-simple-card asoc-simple-card.0: snd-soc-dummy-dai <-> 20203000.i2s mapping ok
>   [   13.660674] bcm2835-i2s 20203000.i2s: **Trying to bind component to card "snd_rpi_hifiberry_dac" but is already bound to card "snd_rpi_simple_card"**
>   [   13.660700]  snd-hifiberry-dac soc:sound: ASoC: failed to instantiate card -19
>   [13.661278] snd-hifiberry-dac soc:sound: snd_soc_register_card() failed: -19

### Contradictings instructions

The two adafruit tutorials for the mic and the amp are conflicting. The mic tutorial tells me to enable the snd-bcm2835 module:

> Add `snd-bcm2835` on its own line, to the modules file as shown below

While the [amp tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-max98357-i2s-class-d-mono-amp) tells me to disable the module:

> However, if you see the following line:
>
> ```
> snd_bcm2835
> ```
>
> Put a `#` in front of it

Please note the different typing using both a dash and an underscore `snd_bcm2835` vs. `snd-bcm2835`.

Comment: Please note that I did cross-post this to the adafruit forum: https://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=143345

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was also getting the same error. But now it is working for me.
First you install I2S microphone as shown here:  https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-i2s-mems-microphone-breakout/raspberry-pi-wiring-and-test

After that while you are installing I2S amplifier go to the detailed installation section and skip the first 2 steps and start from "[Create asound.conf file](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-max98357-i2s-class-d-mono-amp/raspberry-pi-usage#create-asound-dot-conf-file-5-28)" and at last reboot your pi.

**Update**: Please note that using the `aplay.service` which constantly sends audio to the audio output will break the microphone.