# raspberry pi zero I2S record and playback

Tags: gpio, pi-zero-w, output, i2s, adafruit

I am following [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92534/116512) to enable both audio record and playback on RPI zero.

My question is: dose the files [~/.asoundrc](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-i2s-mems-microphone-breakout/raspberry-pi-wiring-and-test#adding-volume-control-5-67) and [/etc/asound.conf](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-max98357-i2s-class-d-mono-amp/raspberry-pi-usage#create-asound-dot-conf-file-5-28) conflict each other?

Sorry, I should just comment below the [post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/90647/i2s-recording-combined-with-i2s-playback), but I don't have 50 reputation to comment

Comment: Your question is unintelligible. Please don't present only links to understand the question and expect that will follow all of them. Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I2S Recording combined with I2S Playback](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/90647/i2s-recording-combined-with-i2s-playback)